# Large shapefile to raster

Tags: postgis, grass-gis, simplify

I have a large shapefile (1 gb) and need to rasterise it. I have tried the following already.

1.) Import it into GRASS using `v.in.ogr` this failed with the error message: ERROR: G_realloc: unable to allocate 498240036 bytes at break_polygons.c:188

2.) My second idea was to use PostGIS. Import the shapefile, resample it at the x,y location of the grid and then export these points and create a grid from xyz. I successfully imported the shapefiles (polygons and points) but intersecting 1 million polygons with 300k points seems to be very slow. I used the following PostGIS satement, maybe there is room for improvement.

```
select polygons.land_id,grid.geom from grid,polygons where grid.geom && polygons.geom and within(grid.geom,polygons.geom)
```

3.) I did also try to use `simplify()` in PostGIS. But I lost to many small polygons (i.e. some areas that were covered only with small polygons became null).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which GRASS Version did you use? It should be at least 6.4. Note that in GRASS 7 large file support is implemented also for vector maps which should help to overcome the indicated problem (also it is much faster).

Comment: I am currently using GRASS 6.4. I will update to 7 soon, thanks for the hint.

Comment: You can get latest precompiled winGRASS 7 binaries here: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html), although I've not used it with such a large shapefile, so you may have the same issues as you did with GRASS. I reckon something like the following should work (with GDAL >= 1.8.0):

```
gdal_rasterize -a AN_ATTRIB -l THE_LAYER -a_nodata -9999 -a_srs EPSG:27700 -co TILED=YES -tr 10 10 -ot Float32 src.shp dest.tif
```

Of course, you will have to play around with some of the options depending on your source shapefile. The most important parameter is -tr which specifies the resolution of a pixel; without it, you may find yourself with a very large raster...

If you want to stick with GRASS, try setting a smaller extent for the rasterization, and split the process up into manageable chunks, then mosaic the rasters into one.

Comment: gdal rasterize did it all in approx 5 min :). Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first intent, could you try running *v.in.ogr* command on a machine having more RAM or swap disk space?

If not you can split it in many files an rasterize each of them before merging them again.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control when doing a rasterization, check out perrygeo's [poly_density.py script](http://code.google.com/p/perrygeo/source/browse/gis-bin/poly_density.py) which uses GDAL under the hood, but can be used for overlapping features or adding conditional evaluations beyond those possible with `gdal_rasterize` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jack the Ripper, do it by parts. From postgis export slices of the data import in grass and convert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a guide on how to rasterize a vector table in PostGIS](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.ca/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html)...