# Rasterize a vector layer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster

Related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/large-shapefile-to-raster) asked here on gis.se and [this thread](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/Rasterize-a-vector-td4997893.html) on postgis-user, has anyone worked out a good solution for in-database rasterization of a vector layer using PostGIS?  It sounds like the necessary functions are available and it is possible to get a valid output, but not one that is readable by GDAL et al. because it has irregular tiles.

To be more specific, I would like to rasterize two distinct vector maps of the US, counties and NBCD mapping zones, to a particular resolution and both aligned with an existing raster.  It is possible to do this with gdal_rasterize, but with some trial and error as I recall -- mainly because the extents of the three inputs do not match, I expect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a guide on how to rasterize a vector table in PostGIS](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.ca/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html)...

Comment: Hi, please do add more detail to your answer. Link only answers discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use ST_AsRaster: https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html

Comment: Hi, please do add more detail to your answer. Link only answers are not good enough.