# OS Terrain 50 into Postgresql/PostGIS for lat/long analysis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am performing analysis using line of sight's and followed a very useful blog post at http://davidrowley.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/calculating-line-of-sight-with-postgis.html which detailed how to load in hgt raster files from http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm into PostGIS.

Eseentially I ran raster2pgsql.exe on the hgt files in a directory to generate a sql file to import into my PostGIS database. The speed is great

I would now like to do the same as this but instead within the UK I would like to use the freely available OS Terrain 50 product available from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html. It appears to be available in 3 formats: [ESRI ® Shape (Contours): 1.1 Gb], [GML (Contours): 1.1 Gb], [ASCII Grid and GML (Grid): 162 Mb].

Could anyone explain the best (and hopefully free) tools/process I could use to take the OS terrain 50 dataset and generate a table in postGIS of rasters? Or at least provide a start as to which of the three formats to use and where to go from there?

We also have the issue of converting the dataset to lat long values rather than grid, although I do also have a simple (large) table of lat, long and z's already created that I could start with if that would be easier?

Comment: You will want to use raster2pgsql on the ASCII Grid, which is in theory one of the supported formats, see [raster2pgsql guide from osgeo](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/raster2pgsql.html). Contour data is not gridded and so will be a lot more complicated to process. I could be wrong, but I think the contours are derived from the grid anyway, so you won't be losing anything by using the grid. As to your second question, you can use ST_Transform to convert to lat/lon, once loaded in OSGB.

Comment: Would I call ST_Transform on the raster column of the new table?

Comment: I see http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Transform.html gives a good description. Given we know the rasters will have come from the 50m grid originally any idea which resamping algorithm would be best to choose?

Comment: Correct about RT_ST_Transform. At that resolution and because you are using this for analytical rather than visual work I would imagine that the resmapling method won't make much difference and nearest neighbour will probably be OK, as you would be looking at a one to one transform. However, I would test this out and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: PostGIS Vector to Raster ST_AsRaster see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30810/rasterize-a-vector-layer-in-postgis

Comment: I'm close to putting an answer together of everything I did, I'm finding some points are coming back with z=0 when they shouldnt. I'm guessing this is down to my tile size selection parameter when using raster2pgsql - i went with 75x75 as this was what I used for srtm, but maybe I need to choose something different here?